# Difference between writing Asynchronous Code with Task and Asynchronous Code with async await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a question about asynchronous programming:

What is difference between async code with task (without async/await) and async code with async/await?

In C#, we can use Task to write async code or method and also we can use keywords.

---

Async Code with Task (Without Async/Await)

```
static Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var work = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
    var workcompleted = work.ContinueWith((x) => { Console.WriteLine("Work Completed!!!"); });
    return work;
}
```

---

Async Code with Async/Await

```
    static async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(10000); });
        Console.WriteLine("Work Completed");
    }
```

---

I'm really appreciate if answer my question.

Comment: You'd use `await Task.Delay` rather than `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Run`. If you made that change you'd see that the second code sample will be much shorter / simpler than the first one.

Comment: Async methods are intended to be non-blocking operations. An await expression in an async method doesn’t block the current thread while the awaited task is running. Instead, the expression signs up the rest of the method as a continuation and returns control to the caller of the async method.

Comment: 1st method is not async. If you run both in a console app, you will notice that the 1st method blocks the UI where as the 2nd doesn't

Comment: Imagine the benefits when there are multiple tasks you need to await with many lines of code in between meaning a mess of `ContinueWith` calls.

Comment: @apomene that's not completely true.  It all depends on what the caller does with the returned Task.  The caller could use `Wait` for either one and cause the code to block, or use `await` to not block with either one.

Comment: The `async` and `await` keywords let you execute asynchronous code by writing a sequence of statements, just like you do when you write synchronous code, i.e. you can call `Console.WriteLine` right after `Task.Run` without using a callback that you pass to `ContinueWith`. It makes your asynchronous code look a lot cleaner.

Comment: @juharr True, but this is just difference between them ???

Comment: One difference is that the first one should return `workcompleted` to be functionally the same.  Otherwise the task you return lets you know when the blocked thread is done sleeping, but not when the console is done writing where as the second returns a task that finishes after the line is written to the console.

Comment: Those two are *basically* the same. There are likely tons of differences regarding exception handling though and I wouldn't do async task-based code without the second example syntax.

Comment: @apomene The first method should not block the UI, that is incorrect. It will construct two tasks, hang the second on the completion of the first, and return the second task (*well, that is what it **should** do, but as juharr has mentioned, it returns the first task, which is likely incorrect). This is how we did task-based async code before async/await.

Comment: So we write async code with async/await when we want to write clean code and they are same ???

Comment: @Argh413 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks you All friends :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In C#, we can use Task to write async code or method and also we can use keywords.

This is *technically* true, but writing asychronous code without `async`/`await` is much more difficult to do correctly. Consider the code sample you have:

```
static Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var work = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
    var workcompleted = work.ContinueWith((x) => { Console.WriteLine("Work Completed!!!"); });
    return work;
}
```

The code above uses the low-level `ContinueWith` method that has [dangerous default behavior](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Specifically, it will implicitly capture the current `TaskScheduler`.

The code above returns a `Task` that completes when the `Task.Run` delegate completes. The `ContinueWith` delegate has *not* run yet when that task is completed, and since `workcompleted` is ignored, any exceptions from the `ContinueWith` delegate are discarded. Calling code cannot know when the `ContinueWith` delegate completes, or whether it completed successfully.

Contrast with the `async`/`await` code, which is shorter, clearer, easier to maintain, and more correct:

```
static async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(10000); });
    Console.WriteLine("Work Completed");
}
```

The code above returns a `Task` that completes when the whole `DoWorkAsync` has finished (including the `WriteLine`). Any exceptions are captured and placed on the task.

In addition, more complex logic such as loops and retries are much more naturally expressed with `async`/`await` rather than continuations with manually-managed state objects.

Under the hood, the `await` in `DoWorkAsync` will end up calling `ContinueWith`. By letting the compiler generate the tricky code correctly, you sidestep a lot of pitfalls and end up with more maintainable code.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Cleary :)